# How can i improve this knn algorithm?

Tags: python, performance-testing, knn

i have tried to develop a KNN from scratch to the Iris data but went in to a sung - very confusing for beginner. Could you spare a minute to help me fix this error      *IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4*? Thanks a lot

I wanted to apply 13 K neighbors, but not going through well

```
from sklearn import datasets # import datasets
import numpy as np # import numpy
iris = datasets.load_iris() # load data 
X = iris.data # get features
y = iris.target # get targets

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

def euclidean_distance(row1, row2):
    distance = 0.0
    for i in range(len(row1)-1):
        distance += (row1[i] - row2[i])**2
    return sqrt(distance)

# Locate the most similar neighbors
def call_neighbors(X_train, X_test, num_neighbors):
    distances = list()
    for train_row in X_train:
        dist = euclidean_distance(X_test, train_row)
        distances.append((X_train, dist))
    distances.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
    neighbors = list()
    for i in range(14):
        neighbors.append(distances[i][0])
    return neighbors
neighbors = call_neighbors(X_train, X_test, 13)
for neighbor in neighbors:
    print(neighbor)
# Make a classification prediction with neighbors
def predict_classification(train, test_row, num_neighbors):
    neighbors = get_neighbors(X_train, X_test, 13)
    output_values = [row[-1] for row in neighbors]
    prediction = max(set(output_values), key=output_values.count)
    return prediction
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are not calculating the distance for all dimensions, since it says "range(len(row1)-1)"?  I'd try letting it run with the "-1" removed, such that it becomes: "range(len(row1))"

Answer (score 0):

`dist = euclidean_distance(X_test, train_row)`

Seems X_test and train_row have different size.

Try printing the shape of the arrays using

```
print(X_test.shape, train_row.shape)
```

and correct them accordingly

Comment: @ Rupesh  thanks, i checked it is ((30, 4), (120, 4))- the test row has less samples, is that a problem - the features are all the same.

Comment: train_row not test_row